# XPath: get all nodes until the first occurrence of an element ?

Tags: dom, xpath

How can I get all the nodes until reaching a specific element ? currently I'm using:

```
br/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::img]
```

This is just an example, I want to get all the nodes after the `<br>` tag until the first occurrence of an `<img>` tag, but this code won't stop until the last `<img>` tag.

To workaround this issue I started from the image tag:

```
img[position()=1]/preceding-sibling::node()[preceding-sibling::br]
```

This is working, but also if I have multiple `<br>` tags it won't stop until the last one.

So how can I get all the nodes until the first occurrence of an element ?

I already searched the other questions, but the answers try to give another solution specific to the provided markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tell how many `img` you want to be really following (in your case all but one):

```
br/following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::img[count(img)-1]]
```